# bash loop exchange placeholder in text file

Tags: bash, loops, variables, text, placeholder

I'm new to bash and I tried to find an answer to my problem:

I have text_file_A a with 5 columns. The first column is a "name" (something like: 6xr8) and the remaining columns are numbers. This text_file_A consists out of 3 rows, where the "name" in column one is not changing, only the numbers in the following columns.

Then I have second text_file_B, where I have 5 placeholder $1, $2, $3, $4, $5. This text file is used to run a `program_A`. I can execute the program with `/path_to_program/program_A text_file_B`.

Now I would like to have a bash script, which reads in the first row of `text_file_A` and replaces the placeholder in `text_file_B` and generates an output_file, which can be executed by `program_A`.

I have no problem to read in from variables from a `text_file_C` and execute the program_C with while loop:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

file="text_file_C.txt"

while IFS= read line
do
    #echo "$line"
    ./program_C.sh $line
done<"$file"
```

But the problem above with 2 textfiles I can not solve.

In some more detail, I would like to loop through all the rows of `text_file_A`. The file looks like this:

```
6xr8      5000   0.1    100 200
6xr8      5000   0.3    300 200
6xr8      5000   0.5    500 200
```

where column 1 refers to $1 , column 2 to $2, column 3 to to $3,  column 4 to to $4 and  column 5 to to $5. Now I would like to have a script, which takes all values in the first row of `text_file_A`  and replace it in $1, $2,$3,$4,$5 in `text_file_B` and write out `text_file_C` and then it does it for the second row and so on...

The file `text_file_B` look like the following:

```
=== simulation ===
generate_micrographs = yes

log_file = $1_file.log

=== sample ===

diameter = 500

thickness_center = 50

thickness_edge = 50

=== particle $1 ===

source = pdb

pdb_file_in = $1.pdb

voxel_size = 0.1

map_file_re_out = $1_map.mrc

map_file_im_out = $1_abs_map.mrc

=== particleset ===

particle_type = $1

particle_coords = file

coord_file_in = $1_coordinates.txt

num_particles = $5

where = volume

coord_file_out = $1_coordinates_1.txt

=== electronbeam ===

acc_voltage = 300

energy_spread = 0.7

gen_dose = yes

dose_per_im = $2

=== optics ===

magnification = 50926.86902

cs = 2.7

cc = 2.7

aperture = 300

focal_length = 3.5

cond_ap_angle = 0.05

gen_defocus = yes

defocus_nominal = $3

=== detector ===

det_pix_x = 4000

det_pix_y = 4000 

pixel_size = 5

gain = 1

use_quantization = yes

dqe = 1

mtf_a = 0

mtf_b = 0.935

mtf_c = 0

mtf_alpha = 0

mtf_beta = 0.64

image_file_out = $1_09818_$4_P$5_$2eA.mrc
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you show examples of the files and what the result should be?

Comment: You only want to read the first line of `text_file_A`, not loop through all the lines?

Answer (score 0):

Read the line of `text_file_A` into a set of variables. Then use those with `sed` to replace the placeholders in `text_file_B`.

```
read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 < text_file_A
sed -e 's/\$1/'"$col1/" -e 's/\$2/'"$col2/" -e 's/\$3/'"$col3/" -e 's/\$4/'"$col4/" -e 's/\$5/'"$col5/" text_file_B > text_file_C
```

To loop over the lines in `text_file_A`, ... add a loop, like this:

```sh
while read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5; do
    sed -e 's/\$1/'"$col1/" -e 's/\$2/'"$col2/" -e 's/\$3/'"$col3/" -e 's/\$4/'"$col4/" -e 's/\$5/'"$col5/" text_file_B > text_file_C
    /path_to_program/program_A text_file_C
done <text_file_A
```

Comment: there is a small typo in the while loop, where you specify col2.